# impossible to delete a container

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

I have created a BlueMix container, and I wanted to delete it. I thus went to the portal, and clicked on the right of the container, the menu, and then chose "delete container". The problem is : after that, the container is not deleted, it is still not marked as "active", but it is impossible to free its IP address, or the RAM used!

It is quite disturbing, and at present I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the ice command line tool (https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_ice_ov.html), you can use commands to release IP addresses and force removal of containers.

Unbind a bound IP address:

```
ice ip unbind {IP_address} {container_name_or_id}
```

Completely release an IP address:

```
ice ip release {IP_address}
```

Force removal of a container:

```
ice rm --force {container_name_or_id}
```

Comment: Yes, it is what i did, and it solved a part of the problem, but the dev team of bluemix managed to solve my error. Anyway, it is useful to have an ice command line in case of problem. Thanks a lot