# IBM Bluemix impossible to delete a container

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

I am experiencing the same problem as [impossible to delete a container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31559315/impossible-to-delete-a-container).

In fact, I deleted the Container from the Bluemix Dashboard and the Container was still active and with the "Deleting..." status.

I also tried to free the IP address as indicated and by using the ICE RM --Force unfostunatelly without success.

```
ice rm --force da4c55c0-13c5-40a1-abc4-d7623583e5c4
Removed container successfully
```

But unfortunately the container is still here and in deleting state :

```
ice ps -a
Container Id                         Name                   Group      Image                          Created      State    Private IP      Public IP       Ports

da4c55c0-13c5-40a1-abc4-d7623583e5c4 boardvisor                        idcware/boardvisor_new:latest  Nov 26 12:15 Deleting                                 []
```

I will appreciate a lot the help of the Bluemix Dev Team in order to solve my error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug and only the DEV team can delete it definitely. 
The container is most likely deleted, but it is still in the database of Bluemix which is read by cf. 
 You can open a new ticket here: https://support.ng.bluemix.net/gethelp/

Remember we will need is Org and space IDs and the container id in question when you will open the ticket.

Comment: Understood, thanks for your quick answer I will create a ticket now

Comment: You are right, my problem is now resolved by ibm devops team manual deleting. Thanks again